C# Get Capslock Status works on Win7 but not Win10
Okay, so i have an GUI Application written in Matlab. And within Matlab i use a bit JAVA to simulate Keypresses to activate CAPSLOCK.
After this, i open my own written on-screen-keyboard, that i made in C# Winforms.
Now problem is, when i open the on-screen keyboard i check for capslock status like in
Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock)

and then i update my onscreen keyboard to show big or small letters accordingly.
Now the problem is...On Notebook with Win7 it works,
BUT on the Touch-PC with Win10 it doesn't work. It doesn't show the correct Capslock
State. Is there a timed discrepancy between activating capslock and check if its activated?
Does Win10 has some other kind of functions to check for capslock?
I tried so many things, like checking in Application.Idle, doesn't show the correct state.
I tried these global system hooks but they don't even work at all. I can press anything i want
and i don't get the hotkey message at all...
Any ideas what could be wrong?
I mean even if i write a little programm like,
                const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
                const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
                keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
                keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
capsLockActivated = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock);

It will show FALSE and thats even in Win7. So its probably timed discrepancy?
Before all that i had a licenced onscreen keyboard but i don't want to pay everytime new licence so i tried writing my own keyboard. Everything works, just the capslock detection won't really...
Oh, i already wrote that above. I tried Application.Idle, i tried keypress event, but that isn't good because my onscreenkeyboard could be off focus. I tried global system hooks but that doesnt work at all, and i dont know why.

Test GetAsyncKeyState(), so you get a state that's not dependent on the thread's message queue. Read the notes there, in case you get 0 as response

hi, what "notes" do you mean? i just tried this for example. i hid my app in the background, then pressed CAPS LOCK on the keyboard to activate it, then clicked on my notifyIcon to show my app, which calls a function when its shown and inside this function i calles GetAsyncKeyState and it says false, but on my keyboard the light for capslock is on. I get that feeling that i am to stupid or reading CAPSLOCK isnt that easy, because its a toggle i assume and everythingh i read iy wether the button is DOWN or UP, but not the exact caps lock state itself wether its active or not...

GetAsyncKeyState() returns a value that lets you know whether the key was pressed since the last read. Control.IsKeyLocked() uses GetKeyState() instead; its return value specifies whether the key is toggled. You need a message loop for that. If this latter method doesn't work for you, then you're probably reading the current CapsLock state from a secondary Thread (not the UI Thread)

I don't use multiple threads. I just tested again with simple script as above mentioned, i simulate keypress to toggle caps lock and then in the last line i check for Control.IsKeyLocked and it shows the old value...So there is a time difference somehow :-( What exactly do you mean with message loop? Should i write a timer or what? :/

Using Messages and Message Queues - Message loop in Microsoft Windows -- If you are changing the state of keys a Keyboard in a closed procedure (e.g., the Click event handler of a Button - or any other synchronous procedure), the actions performed there are completed when the procedure exits (or you return the control flow to the main UI Thread, for example using BeginInvoke() to execute code asynchronously - or await Task.Delay())
